# Não consigo deixar JButton em cima de JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um `JPanel`, e dentro dele um `JLabel` de mesmo tamanho. O `JLabel` tem um ícone associado a ele, funcionando como um wallpaper. Quando tento colocar um JButton em cima do JLabel, o NetBeans reposiciona os 2. Alguém saberia me responder o porquê ?

Desde já eu agradeço.

Comment: Nunca uses o `jLabel` para colocar imagens mas sim indicações com onde colocar email, password, etc. A principal função e essa. O `jPanel` tem propriedades para isso.

Answer (score 4):

É possível adicionar um fundo diretamente ao `JPanel`, ao invés de usar um `JLabel` para isso pois apesar de todos os componentes de swing herdarem de `JComponent` e, portanto, poderem ser *contêineres* de outros componentes, *JButtons*, *JLabels*, *JTextfields* e alguns outros não possuem implementação alguma de um `LayoutManager`, o que torna componentes como `JPanel` mais apropriado para essa finalidade, pois já possuem implementação de layout.

A classe abaixo foi adaptada [**deste link**](http://wiki.portugal-a-programar.pt/dev_geral:java:jpanel_imagem_fundo)(em português e muito bem explicado), você tem que passar a referencia da imagem, que o `JPanel` se adapta ao tamanho dela:

```
class myCustomPanel extends JPanel {

    private Image background;

    public myCustomPanel(URL path) {
        this.background = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
        setOpaque(false);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return background.getWidth(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return background.getHeight(this);
    }
}
```

Exemplo funcional da classe acima, com um `JButton` adicionado:

```
package example;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackgroundPanel extends JFrame {

    public BackgroundPanel() throws MalformedURLException {
        //se a imagem estiver no projeto, basta referenciar ela
        // pela localização do pacote
        //ex: URL path = getClass().getResource("caminho/da/suaImage.jpg");
        URL path = new URL("http://www.itinterns.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Java_620X0.jpg");
        JPanel p = new myCustomPanel(path);
        p.add(new JButton("botao"));
        this.add(p);
        this.pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class myCustomPanel extends JPanel {

        private Image background;

        public myCustomPanel(URL path) {
            this.background = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
            setOpaque(false);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public int getWidth() {
            return background.getWidth(this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight() {
            return background.getHeight(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BackgroundPanel b = new BackgroundPanel();
                    b.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    b.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Que resulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom Diego, aprendi mais um modo de fazer. Me ajudou também.

Comment: @ismael pra falar a verdade, eu nunca havia tentado fazer isso, apesar de imaginar que havia um jeito de como fazer. O bom é que também acabei aprendendo como :D

Comment: Daria uma pergunta do porquê a IDE do netbeans não permite esse comportamento. Com o VS não tem segredo.

Comment: @ismael sua reposta não estava errada, de fato, eu que havia entendido mal a pergunta, entendi que ele queria dispor o bota-o em cima do label(verticalmente), e não sobrepor. Sua resposta estava correta, não é possivel dispor um componente acima do outro, se o debaixo também não for um container. Tanto que fiz referencia a sua resposta na minha.